# Ubuntu desktop 18.04 to Server

Tags: server

I am a noob to Linux. I installed Ubuntu desktop version 18.04.is it possible to install server on the desktop?Should I remove the desktop version? any suggestions, please

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I'm no expert, but I see Ubuntu-Server as a method of install for machines that re going to be used as servers. They contain the base of Ubuntu, plus common tools used by servers (no DEsktops, as they just consume resources & don't help serving functions).  Ubuntu DEsktop contains a huge proportion of the same tools, but include a DEsktop & apps usually wanted on DEsktops (music etc). They don't include everything found in the server edition (eg. openssh-server won't be installed, as DEsktops usually only need client), but that's easily added.  Both are starting points.

Comment: Since I was new to Linux, I installed desktop version on separate Hard disk. I am interested in installing server version now. Wondering if folks up here can solve my problem.

Comment: The Desktop edition includes everything (well, *almost* everything) which is included in the Server edition. So basically *you already have* everything running on the machine.